# Add a picturebox on the form via a class C#

Tags: c#

im trying to make a class for a picturebox and add it to my form and i just cant get it, im not getting any errors, it just wont add. Also if i was to add a mousedown event to the picturebox, how would i do that with the class? heres my code

```
    public class Display : FrmMain
{
    PictureBox display = new PictureBox();

    public int _X { set; get; }
    public int _Y { set; get; }

    public int _Width { set; get; }
    public int _Height { set; get; }

    public Display(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        this._X = x;
        this._Y = y;
        this._Width = width;
        this._Height = height;
    }

    public PictureBox add()
    {
        return display;
    }
}
```

when the form loads

```
        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Display display1 = new Display(0, 0, 100, 100);
        display1.add();
        Display display2 = new Display(0, 0, 100, 100);
        display2.add();
        Display display3 = new Display(0, 0, 100, 100);
        display3.add();
        Display display4 = new Display(0, 0, 100, 100);
        display4.add();
    }
```

Comment: Confusing code.  Why is Display inheriting from frmMain?  At some point, you have to add your control to the container: `this.Controls.Add(myControl);`

Comment: because thats what i thought i needed to add it on the form. i took it off and tried `Display display1 = new Display(0, 0, 100, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(display1);` which gave me a cant convert error

Comment: Well, it's very unclear what the Display class is supposed to do.  I would remove that code.  Just create a new PictureBox and add it to the form's Control collection.

Comment: Try my answer @RachelDockter

Comment: it cant be that unclear, its a class to add a picturebox and i want to call it multiple times to add a picturebox on the form

Comment: The unclear part is: why not just use a PictureBox?

Comment: because i need a few and i want to add them programmaticly so when i click a button on screen, i can create a new one

Comment: Right.  Just use a PictureBox.  `PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();`  If you really need another class to do this, you probably want to *inherit* from the control: `public class Display : PictureBox`  You would remove that `display` variable and just refer to `this` inside that class.

Comment: I tried what i think u mean and im having no luck, im not that experienced so i dont really know what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LarsTech said to add the controll to your form use: `this.Controls.Add(display.add());` your add function returns a control so add that control to the forms controls.

Comment: its runs with no errors but nothing is adding to the form

Comment: You still make it like before and do this.Controls.Add(display1.Add());?

Comment: I cant test anything at the moment but does a picturebox with no picture display anything?

Comment: that might be it, im going to try add a back color and see if that works

Comment: You dont set the width and height for display

Comment: Set display.Width etc. Before you return it (in add method) or when you make an instance of the class (public display)

Comment: "cannot modifty the return value of 'control.location' because its not a variable" thats the error i get when i try assign an X value to my display variable in add();

Comment: that works thanks, i cant help thinking im doing it in a really bad way but oh well it works

Comment: It does the job :)